Use Intellisense for ASP.NET Core areas, controllers and actions in Custom View Components
I guess everyone is familiar with the ASP.NET Core taghelpers like form where you can use the attributes like asp-area to get intellisense for the areas, controllers or actions. I would like the same autocomplete (and therefore refactor) functionality for custom view components.
I checked out the code of the form tag helper but there seams to be nothing that refers to intellisense. So is this even possible or is this handled inside intellisense and there is nothing I can do to make intellisense "see" my intention?
So what I want is the same highlighting and logik in my vc:table as in the ASP.NET Core form taghelper.


If you want to let the intellisense also work for your custom taghelper, you  should write the Visual Studio Extension (VSIX) by yourself.

I was just wondering is this is possible with some compiler or property attributes or something that helps intellisense.

In my opinion, there is no such things which could help the IntelliSense based on my knowledge.

According to my google/github research I came to the same conclusion. But I figured that maybe someone here has an idea.
